# Alerting users on website through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to make a notification system that notifies users when they are assigned to a ticket, or when a new ticket is added to the database.

The system itself, that I already have, works except that it only sends the notification to the first user who receives the ajax request. Is there any way to make it so that everyone who is suppose to receive the notification, actually receives the notification?

My code:
javascript:

```
        function checkUpdates()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'ajax/checkDB.php',   // a webservice or other URL that queries the database
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('Connected and executed PHP page... '+data);
                        if (data.hasChanged == "true") {
                            playSound('img/notif2');
                            notifyAdmin();
                            console.log('Updated Tickets Page...');
                            $("#contents").load("dynamic/tickets.php");
                            $("#contents").fadeTo("fast", 1);
                        }

                        if (data.newAssigned == "true") {
                            playSound('img/notif2');
                            notifyUser();
                            console.log('Updated Tickets Page...');
                            $("#contents").load("dynamic/tickets.php");
                            $("#contents").fadeTo("fast", 1);
                        }
                    }
                 });
            }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval("checkUpdates()", 3000);  // Calls the function every 3 seconds
        });
```

My php script (checkDB.php):

```
<?php
include("../static/config.php");
session_start();

header("Content-Type: text/json");

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT notify FROM tickets WHERE notify='0'");
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($row_cnt > 0) {
            $hasChanged = 'true';
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tickets SET notify='1' WHERE notify='0'");
        } else {
            $hasChanged = 'false';
        }

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT notify,Assigned FROM tickets WHERE Completeness='1' AND notify='1'");
        $row_cnt2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

        if($row_cnt2 > 0) {
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    if(strcmp($_SESSION['Name'],$row2['Assigned']) == 0) {
                        $newAssigned = 'true';
                    } else {
                        $newAssigned = 'false';
                    }
                }
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tickets SET notify='2' WHERE Completeness='1' AND notify='1'");
        } else {
            $newAssigned = 'false';
        }

        echo json_encode(array('newAssigned' => $newAssigned, 'hasChanged' => $hasChanged));

?>
```

Here is a rundown of my exact intentions:
User logs into system, and is given administrative rights if granted.
User loads the tickets page, which lists all the tickets along with this javascript that I gave you
the javascript loads checkDB.php every 3 seconds, basically running a check against the database for a 'notify' value of 0, and if at least 1 exists, is updated in the database to '1' and is returned as true to the ajax call - which sends out notifications.

Again this works for the 1st user who is loaded into the page, but after that, obviously there are no more 'notify=0' in the database as they have already been updated, so they are not shown the notification.

It was requested that I share my database structures.
tickets:

```
UniqueID - Unique ID per ticket (always unique)
Requester - Whoever submitted the ticket.
Problem - Description of the given issue.
Assigned - User who is assigned to the ticket.
Completeness - The level of completeness (0-4)
Times - Times listed for ticket start, assigned, etc
notified - Used in old ticket system (I plan to get rid of it)
Urgency - Selected by requester, how urgent the ticket is
Location - Location in our warehouse assistance is needed.
FollowUp - currently not in use, will be used to submit follow ups.
isProject - (0-1) is project or not
additionalTechs - Lists additional users on a ticket (Not important for question)
notify - (0-2) at 0, ticket is new and notif should be sent to admins which should set this to 1, when it is 1 it should send a notif to users that are attached to the ticket.
```

Techs Database:

```
UniqueID
Username
Password
Name
Level
Disabled
LastTimeSeen
needsNotify (Used in old system, plan to remove)
```

I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Whats the table structure for tickets? List the columns please

Comment: Two columns  .... user and notified. If user is null, it hasn't been assigned. Queries should be user based

Comment: It looks like you need to limit your SQL queries to the current user

Comment: @charlietfl They ARE user based. User will never equal null. When a user logs in, they are stored in a php session, e.g $_SESSION['Name'] - I'm checking it against a column in my tickets database called 'Assigned'

Comment: @Kisaragi give me a moment and I will add it.

Comment: @Kisaragi I added my database structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with websockets, or socket.io.
Then the js of multiple clients will connect with that socket will notify all connected people about they ticket

Comment: Hi Luan. Better use Comment box to give suggestions.

Comment: Could you explain in-depth how these things work? I've never used them before.

Comment: Websocket is like a tunnel, where the browser communicates with the server1 and stays open until you close it. That is very secure, by the way.
(There are other applications)
It is widely used to create chat rooms where people connect and when the server realized that received a new message, send it to all who are connected to it.
One nice plugin is http://socket.io/

Comment: Right, I saw _what it is_ when you mentioned it earlier, my question was how it works, e.g how to get socket.io to work for my problem specifically

Answer (score 0):

You can change your update statement to something like:

```
UPDATE tickets SET notify='1' WHERE notify='0' and Assigned = ''//some user id passed
```

Comment: I don't think that would work, because admins aren't assigned to the ticket. I'm currently trying to make sure the notification is sent to all the admins, which is set in a session variable upon login.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what it is you're trying to do / asking.

Comment: When a ticket is submitted, all admins on the site should be sent a notification